# Relationship with Swift

Tags: swift

I have a code:

```
extension Person {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var personDevice: NSSet?

}


extension Device {

@NSManaged var deviceName: String?
@NSManaged var device: Person?

}


class Person: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object        subclass

     func addNewDevice(device:Device) {
         let newDevice = self.mutableSetValueForKey("personDevice")
         newDevice.addObject(device)
     }

}
```

and call this:

```
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    let contact = Person(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)


    let entityDevice = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Device", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    let device = Device(entity: entityDevice!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)


    contact.name = "Test"
    device.deviceName = "3310"
    contact.addNewDevice(Device())
```

But I get error.

> "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on
>   NSManagedObject class 'Test.Device' "

How fix it, please?

Comment: I suppose that you want to learn relationships in Core Data. If so you can check [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Databases_in_Swift_using_Core_Data)

Comment: Look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113508/video-tutorial-beginning-core-data-part-3-relationships)